# How to write the jest-mock-function for @react-navigation/drawer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm having issue while running `npm test` it shows this error in terminal and it's happening with only the @react-navigation/drawer:

> ● **Test suite failed to run**
>
> ```
> TypeError: (0 , _drawer.createDrawerNavigator) is not a function
>
>   13 | 
>   14 | const Stack = createStackNavigator();
> > 15 | const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
>      |                ^
>   16 | 
>   17 | import AddUser from './src/screens/AddUserScreens/AddUser';
>   18 | import SuccessScreen from './src/screens/CommonScreens/Success';
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (App.js:15:16)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/App-test.js:7:1)
> ```

I'm using **jest** and **react-native-testing-library** package and also added jest setup file and added the following:

```
import React from 'react';

jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () =>
  require('react-native-reanimated/mock'),
);

jest.mock(
  '@react-navigation/drawer',
  async () =>
    await {
      createDrawerNavigator: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        Navigator: ({children}) => <>{children}</>,
        Screen: ({children}) => <>{children}</>,
      }),
    },
);
```

*here is my jest preset*

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js",
      "./jest-setup.js"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|native-base-.*|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    }
  }
```

**Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^2.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
```